# Easy way of finding the residue of $\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

In the lecture note I am reading, it finds that the pole of $\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$ is at $w_1=e^{i\pi/3}$ and $w_2=e^{2i\pi/3}$ in the upper half plane. It is obvious that those poles are simple, and it asserts that

$\text{Res}_{w_j}(f)=\frac{1}{Q'(w_j)}=\frac{1}{4w_j^3+2w_j}$ where $Q(z)=z^4+z^2+1$.

I only know the formula for finding a simple pole $\text{res}_{z_0}f=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$.

How does the above equation hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, where $p,q$ are analytic at $z_0$, with $p(z_0)\neq 0,\,q(z_0)=0,\,q'(z_0)\neq 0$, then $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, and you can write $$\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}=\frac{p(z_0)+p'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\cdots}{q'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\cdots}.$$ Now you can multiply by $z-z_0$, take the limit for $z\rightarrow z_0$ and you will get the formula $$Res(f,z_0)=\frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! So this formula is for finding the residue of rational function and it used the taylor expansion?

Comment: yes, and it can be generalized for poles of any order using the Taylor series argument.